# How to make chrome not swallow bluetooth play/pause event?

Tags: chrome-for-android, nexus-5, bluetooth-audio

On my nexus 5, when listening to music, I can pause it on my headset by pressing the pause / play button.  It seems to work regardless of what app in focus.  Unless that app happens to be chrome.

The same follows for starting music (same button).  If I am browsing the web and hit this button it does not work.  It seems like chrome is swallowing this event somehow.

**How can I prevent this from happening?**

Comment: The foreground activity gets the first opportunity to handle the event. You've already observed that Chrome swallows it. What more do you want to know?

Comment: Hi @DanHulme I have reworded the question.  I want to know how to work around this problem.  I thought there might be a setting somewhere, but I have been unable to find it, if it exists.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a solution. I think the only answer might be "report it to Google and wait for them to fix it".